# Security Message in FireFox appearing

Tags: firefox

Can someone please let me know how to prevent the security question in firefox from constantly appearing each time I go to website?

[image: firefox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address starting with `192.168.x.x` is internal to your network.
Your browser was probably set to go there by default (check your "proxy" settings for Firefox).
Another possibility is that proxy settings were changed at the system level.

A possible scenario where such thing could cause this is if you installed a program (malware?) that runs some local server and changed your browser proxy to go there by default.
Such malware could record everything you do online, including sensitive stuff.

I'd suggest running some antivirus and anti-malware programs, and manually make sure your FF proxy and pc proxy is set to "none".

Comment: uval, thanks for responding. I couldnt find the FF proxy in order to set it to none.

Comment: edit menu > preferences > advanced > network > Connection settings.

Comment: check your pc proxy as well (search Google how to do it in your operating system)

Comment: Great! was it FF proxy or the PC proxy? And don't forget to run anti virus